# node-pg returns error on (now() + interval '6h 55m')::date

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I am using node-pg and trying to execute the following query:

```
var q = "SELECT * FROM parentorder WHERE trade_date = (now() + interval '6h 55m')::date ORDER BY create_us DESC LIMIT 50";

        // Parent Orders
        db.query(q, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result.rows);
        });
```

The query throws this error

```
error: operator does not exist: character = date
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message:

> error: operator does not exist: character = date

says that there is no `=` operator for comparing `character` and `date` so your problem is that `trade_date` is a `character` column but you're trying to treat it as a date.

You should change your `trade_date` to a real date column:

```
alter table parentorder alter column trade_date type date using trade_date::date
```

If the date format is weird and you can't simply cast the strings to `date` then you'll have to clean up the formats before trying to [ALTER TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) or come up with an expression you can use for the conversion instead of a simple `trade_date::date`.

If you don't want to give `trade_date` a sensible type or if you can't, then you could use [`to_char`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) to format `now() + interval '6h 55m'` as a string:

```
WHERE trade_date = to_char(now() + interval '6h 55m', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

You'll have to adjust the `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format to match whatever you have in `trade_date`. You could also try casting `trade_date`:

```
where trade_date::date = (now() + interval '6h 55m')::date
```

You might run into some indexing problems if you try this though. Anyway, I think you'd be better off with a real `date` column, everything (including indexes) will work better that way.

Comment: Great answer. As far as I know, the simple case of `trade_date::date`, if it works, doesn't need the `USING` clause, but it's a powerful tool as it can involve any expression, even involving other columns. There are a few useful notes and examples in the linked documentation page.

Comment: @IMSoP: I'm pretty sure you do need the USING clause to get the cast applied, otherwise you'll get a "cannot be cast to type date" error from the ALTER TABLE. Seems a bit silly but reality does have that tendency.

Comment: *fiddles...* [hm, seems you're right](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3fe85/1). Man, PG really is picky about those automatic casts isn't it!

Comment: @IMSoP: PostgreSQL is wonderfully picky, I don't want a database making any guesses about what I want: software bugs can be fixed, data bugs are often permanent and unfixable.